# Проверка логина на наличие недопустимых символов

Tags: javascript

*Как должно быть*:
Если пользователь вводит какой-либо символ в форму кроме английских букв и цифр - появляется предупреждение о неверном заполнении формы.

*Как выходит*:
Пользователь может обойти эту защиту от нежелательных символов, если в начале введёт английскую букву или цифру. Например, может написать `1Информация`, и проверку это пройдёт. Как это исправить?

```
if (!login.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)) {
    var div = document.querySelector("#login");
    div.className = "false";
    div.innerHTML = "Логин должен состоять из латинских <br> букв и/или цифр!";
    delete alogin;
    alogin = false;
}
else {
    div.className = "true";
    div.innerHTML = "✓Логин не занят";
    delete alogin;
    alogin = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы проверяете логин на наличие допустимых символов. Нужно же проверять на наличие недопустимых символов:

```js
function checkLogin(login) {
  if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(login))
    console.log("Есть недопустимые символы в логине", login);
  else
    console.log("Логин корректен", login);
}

checkLogin("Correct123");
checkLogin("Incorrect 123");
checkLogin("1Информация");
checkLogin("Информация");
```